# Join Tables to return 1 or 0 based on multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a project management website and have been asked for a new feature in a review meeting section.

A meeting is held to determine whether to proceed to the next phase, and I need to maintain a list of who attended each phase review meeting.  I need to write an SQL query to return all people, with an additional column that states they have already been added before.

There are two tables involved to get my desired result, with the relevant columns listed below:

```
Name: PersonList
ID | Name | Division 

Name: reviewParticipants
ProjectID | PersonID | GateID
```

The query I am looking for is something that returns all people in PersonList, with an additional "hasAttended" bit that is TRUE if reviewParticipants.ProjectID = 5 AND reviewParticpants.CurrentPhase = 'G0' ELSE FALSE.

```
PersonName | PersonID | hasAttended
Mr Smith | 1 | 1
Mr Jones | 2 | 0
```

I am not sure how to structure such a query with multiple conditions in a (left?) join, that would return as a different column name and data type, so I would appreciate if anybody can point me in the right direction?

With the result of this query I am going to add a series of checkboxes, and use this additional bit to mark it checked, or not, for page refreshes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` as well:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.*
      ,CASE WHEN rp.id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS hasAttended
  FROM personlist p
  LEFT JOIN reviewParticipants rp ON rp.personid = p.id
                                  AND rp.projectid = 5
                                  AND rp.currentphase = 'GO'
```

I agree with Gordon Linoff: I would prefer an int or tinyint over a bit value,

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists` to see if there is a matching row.

```
select p.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from reviewParticipants rp
                          where rp.personid = p.id and
                                rp.projectid = 5 and
                                rp.currentphase = 'GO'
                         )
             then 1 else 0 end)
from personlist p;
```

I see no reason to prefer a bit over an integer, but you can return a bit if you really prefer.

Answer (score 0):

This will do :

```
select a.* from PersonList a where a.hasAttended=1 and 
a.Id in (select b.PersonId from reviewParticipants b 
where b.ProjectID =5 and exists (
select 1 from reviewParticipants c where c.CurrentPhase = 'G0'and
c.Project =b.projectId
)
)
```

Comment: As far as I understood, `hasAttended` is the value which has to be estimated by the projectId and CurrentPhase...

Comment: Hi Tyron, hasAttended is simply supposed to represent that the person is found in reviewParticipants, as matching the project ID and gate number.  I opted for bit as there is no other option but Yes or No

Comment: @DeafPotato yes, my comment was addressed to Mr. Nikhil Sugandh - in his example he uses hasAtteded in the `WHERE` condition.
Even if there is only yes or no, life will be much easier with `int` / `tinyint` - we ran into problems with `bit` as soon as it came to processing the data in other programs. But after all, it's your decision. :-)